# Multithreading не работает должным образом

Tags: c++, многопоточность, сортировка

Я пишу `quicksort` с использованием многопоточности. Это работает, но при больших или маленьких размерах массива почему-то работает лишь один поток.

Я использовал два контейнера `std::set`, чтобы сохранять ид входных потоков и тех, которые задействованы в работе, а затем использовал их для вывода. Однако, как видно из вывода консоли, многопоточность работает только с массивами размером 10.000, 100.000 и 1.000.000. Почему так происходит?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <ostream>
#include <random>
#include <limits>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <set>


template < class fwdIter >
using FunctionPair = std::pair< std::string, std::function<void(fwdIter, fwdIter)> >;

template < class T, class Generator, template < class > class Distribution >
auto createRandomGeneratorFunc(T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max())
{
    static auto distrib = Distribution<T>{ min, max };
    static std::random_device rd;
    static auto gen = Generator(rd());
    return [&]() { return distrib(gen); };
}
template <class fwdIter>
void sortTest(fwdIter first, fwdIter last);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto randomIntFunc = createRandomGeneratorFunc<int, std::mt19937, std::uniform_int_distribution>();

    std::vector<size_t> vecSizes = { 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000 };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vecSizes.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "\nTest " << i << ". Size: " << vecSizes[i] << ":" << std::endl;
        std::vector<int> arr1(vecSizes[i]);
        std::generate(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), [&randomIntFunc]() { return randomIntFunc(); });
        sortTest(arr1.begin(), arr1.end());
    }
    return 0;
}


template < class fwdIter >
std::vector< FunctionPair<fwdIter> > getVectorOfSortFuncs()
{
    FunctionPair<fwdIter> pair2(std::string("QuickSortThreads  "), std::function<void(fwdIter, fwdIter)>(QuickSortThreads<fwdIter>));
    std::vector< FunctionPair<fwdIter> > sortFunctions;
    sortFunctions.push_back(pair2);
    return sortFunctions;
}

template <class fwdIter>
void sortTest(fwdIter first, fwdIter last)
{
    using std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration;

    auto sortFunctions = getVectorOfSortFuncs<fwdIter>();
    for (const auto& funcPair : sortFunctions)
    {
        // Sorting
        auto timeBegin = steady_clock::now();
        funcPair.second(first, last);
        auto timeEnd = steady_clock::now();

        // Print function name and work time
        std::cout << "  " << funcPair.first << ": "
            << (std::is_sorted(first, last) ? "sorted" : "not sorted")
            << " | " << duration<float, std::milli>(timeEnd - timeBegin).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
    }
}


template < class fwdIter >
void QuickSortThreads(fwdIter first, fwdIter last)
{
    const unsigned int numberOfThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    if (numberOfThreads < 1)
    {
        throw std::exception("Number of thread < 1");
    }

    std::atomic<bool> bRun(false);   // threads run
    std::atomic<int> nWorkThreads = 0;   // number of proccessing threads
    std::mutex mut;
    std::condition_variable condVarNotEmpty;
    std::queue< std::pair<fwdIter, fwdIter> > queueArrayParts;   // queue of parts
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    // --TEST
    std::set<std::thread::id> i_threads;
    std::set<std::thread::id> w_threads;

    queueArrayParts.push(std::pair<fwdIter, fwdIter>(first, last));

    // Thread func (sort processing)
    auto process = [&i_threads, &w_threads, &mut, &queueArrayParts, &nWorkThreads, &bRun, &condVarNotEmpty]() {
        // --ADDED
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
            i_threads.emplace(std::this_thread::get_id());   // --TEST
        }
        //

        while (true)
        {
            // --REMOVED
            //i_threads.emplace(std::this_thread::get_id());   // --TEST
            //

            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);   // queue mutex
            condVarNotEmpty.wait(lock, [&queueArrayParts, &bRun] { return !queueArrayParts.empty() || !bRun; });   // lock

            // Terminating a thread
            if (queueArrayParts.empty() && !bRun)
            {
                std::cout << "break\n";
                break;
            }
            ++nWorkThreads;

            // Get part of the array for processing
            fwdIter first = queueArrayParts.front().first;
            fwdIter last = queueArrayParts.front().second;
            w_threads.emplace(std::this_thread::get_id());   // --TEST
            // Pop this part from the queue
            queueArrayParts.pop();
            // Queue unlock
            lock.unlock();

            // Sorting
            if (first != last)
            {
                auto pivot = *std::next(first, std::distance(first, last) / 2);
                auto middle1 = std::partition(first, last,
                    [pivot](const auto& em) { return em < pivot; });
                auto middle2 = std::partition(middle1, last,
                    [pivot](const auto& em) { return !(pivot < em); });
                // Add new parts and start other threads
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mut);
                    queueArrayParts.push(std::pair<fwdIter, fwdIter>(first, middle1));
                    queueArrayParts.push(std::pair<fwdIter, fwdIter>(middle2, last));
                }
                condVarNotEmpty.notify_one();
                condVarNotEmpty.notify_one();
            }

            --nWorkThreads;
            // Stop sorting
            // --ADDED bRun == true 
            if (queueArrayParts.empty() && bRun == true && nWorkThreads == 0)
            {
                bRun = false;
                // --ADDED
                condVarNotEmpty.notify_all();
                //
            }
        }

    };

    // Start threads work
    // --ADDED
    bRun = true;
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(process));
    }
    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

    // --TEST
    std::cout << "  Threads:\n";
    std::cout << "Input threads: "; std::for_each(i_threads.cbegin(), i_threads.end(), [](auto val) { std::cout << " " << val; }); std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Work threads: "; std::for_each(w_threads.cbegin(), w_threads.end(), [](auto val) { std::cout << " " << val; }); std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**Вывод:**

```
Test 0. Size: 10:
  Threads:
Input threads:  3536 10752 11600 15388 15640 18104 18680 20308 20348 23496 24156 24640
Work threads:  18680
  QuickSortThreads  : sorted | 18.6644ms

Test 1. Size: 100:
  Threads:
Input threads:  1144 7896 14352 16396 19304 19384 20320 21636 21924 22496 23688 24328
Work threads:  23688
  QuickSortThreads  : sorted | 11.6995ms

Test 2. Size: 1000:
  Threads:
Input threads:  2228 9928 15580 16008 20028 20984 23492 24004 25120 25416 26304 26584
Work threads:  24004
  QuickSortThreads  : sorted | 11.1096ms

Test 3. Size: 10000:
  Threads:
Input threads:  10820 17024 17208 18216 18488 18920 19216 22224 22676 23124 24380 25712
Work threads:  10820 17024 17208 18216 18488 18920 19216 22224 23124 25712
  QuickSortThreads  : sorted | 16.4296ms

Test 4. Size: 100000:
  Threads:
Input threads:  3088 5980 6556 14548 18184 18332 18448 20284 21024 21520 25548 26164
Work threads:  3088 5980 6556 18184 18332 18448 20284 21024 21520 25548 26164
  QuickSortThreads  : sorted | 51.7859ms

Test 5. Size: 1000000:
  Threads:
Input threads:  6984 9700 10496 13228 14612 16884 18992 20828 21228 23516 24492 24508
Work threads:  13228 21228 24492 24508
  QuickSortThreads  : sorted | 266.152ms

Test 6. Size: 10000000:
  Threads:
Input threads:  8432 8756 8928 8992 16320 17260 21464 23236 23828 25084 25848 26532
Work threads:  16320
  QuickSortThreads  : sorted | 2245.86ms

Test 7. Size: 100000000:
  Threads:
Input threads:  1560 2040 6472 8752 10508 18308 21780 21928 23732 25048 25152 25480
Work threads:  6472
  QuickSortThreads  : sorted | 22395.7ms
```

**PS:** Это только часть кода. Я удалил все остальное, оставив только нужное для запуска. Тут все работает исправно, кроме самого алгоритма сортировки.
Основной алгоритм взят с cppreference (к сожалению, ссылку не смог найти, возможно страница уже удалена или изменена) и переделан под мнопоточность.
Целью как раз является изучение (повторение) на практике каких-либо новых фич из последних (или не совсем) стандартов плюсов. Текущий код можно запустить только с включенной поддержкой с++ 20

Comment: Мне кажется проблема с condition variable. Я бы перенес notify внутрь блока, т.е. **до неявного (по окончанию блока) unlock mutex**, на котором другие потоки выполяют `condVarNotEmpty.wait(lock, ...)`. Впрочем, я плохо понимаю весь этот современный С++ с лямбдами и могу ошибаться в своих оценках, что именно тут параллельно происходит. (Да, далеко вы ушли от [древней очевидной реализации](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html#58))

Comment: Еще пара замечаний. 1) Вы уверены, что операция `i_threads.emplace(std::this_thread::get_id());` **thread safety?**  2) сколько ни смотрел на код, так и не нашел, где `bRun` устанавливается в true?

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы. Второй комментарий решает проблему. Это работает. Однако появилась другая проблема. Я постараюсь обновить код и добавить дополнительное описание в ближайшие дни. Спасибо!

Comment: Я разобрался со всеми ошибками и обновил код. @avp , не могли бы вы в отдельном сообщении указать решение проблемы (о том, что нужно bRun присвоить true), чтобы я пометил его, как решение проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас переменная `bRun`, используемая во всех threads, инициализирована `false` и нигде не устанавливается в `true`